# How to to iterate over hrefs with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping, href

I've been trying to get all the hrefs of a news article home page. In the end, I want to create something that gives me the n-most used words from all the news articles. To do that, I figured I needed the hrefs first to then click on them one after another.

With a lot of help from another user of this platform, this is the code I've got right now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://ad.nl'

# launch firefox with your url above
# note that you could change this to some other webdriver (e.g. Chrome)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# click the "accept cookies" button
btn = driver.find_element_by_name('action')
btn.click()

# grab the html. It'll wait here until the page is finished loading
html = driver.page_source

# parse the html soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.lower(), "html.parser")
articles = soup.findAll("article")

for i in articles:
    article = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ankeiler')
    hrefs = article.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    print(hrefs)
driver.quit()
```

It gives me the first href I think, but it won't iterate over the next ones. It just gives me the first href as many times as it has to iterate. Does anyone know how I make it go to the next href instead of being stuck on the first one?

PS. if anyone has some suggestions on how to further do my little project, feel free to share them as I have a lot of things yet to learn about Python and programming in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve on my previous answer, I have written a full solution to your problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://ad.nl'

#Set up selenium driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

#Click the accept cookies button
btn = driver.find_element_by_name('action')
btn.click()

#Get the links of all articles
article_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="ankeiler__link"]')
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in article_elements]

#Create a dictionary for every word in the articles
words = dict()

#Iterate through every article
for link in links:
    #Get the article
    driver.get(link)

    #get the elements that are the body of the article
    article_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="article__paragraph"]')

    #Initalise a empty string
    article_text = ''

    #Add all the text from the elements to the one string
    for element in article_elements:
        article_text+= element.text + " "

    #Convert all character to lower case  
    article_text = article_text.lower()

    #Remove all punctuation other than spaces
    for char in article_text:
        if ord(char) > 122 or ord(char) < 97:
            if ord(char) != 32:
                article_text = article_text.replace(char,"")

    #Split the article into words
    for word in article_text.split(" "):
        #If the word is already in the article update the count
        if word  in words:
            words[word] += 1
        #Otherwise make a new entry
        else:
            words[word] = 1

#Print the final dictionary (Very large so maybe sort for most occurring words and display top 10)
#print(words)

#Sort words by most used
most_used = sorted(words.items(), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)

#Print top 10 used words
print("TOP 10 MOST USED: ")
for i in range(10):
    print(most_used[i])

driver.quit()
```

Works fine for me, let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: If only I could speak dutch, then I'd understand what the most common words were :)

Comment: This is amazing... Only thing I'll have to add is that it doesn't count the 'the' 'and' 'a' 'an' words. I do have some questions though. Does the driver, get(link) replace the value of driver from ad.nl to whatever the link is? Why do you have to make a new empty string instead of only using element.text? How'd you know that ord has to be >122 or <97, where can I find the corresponding characters with a number? Thank you so much!

Comment: Answer to the first question is yes, the driver changes from say "ad.nl" to "ad.nl/article1". The answer to the second question is yes, because there are multiple paragraphs for each article so you need to add all the text for all the paragraphs together. I knew the ord() had to be between 122 and 97 because that (97-122 ) is the ascii numbers for characters a-z. Also worth noting that 32 is a space, because we don't want to remove the spaces as they separate the words. You can get these number by looking up "ASCII table".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using beautiful soup, how about this?

```
articles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('article')

for i in articles:
    href = i.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    print(href)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all hrefs in an article you can do:

```
hrefs = article.find_elements_by_xpath('//a')
#OR article.find_element_by_css_selector('a')

for href in hrefs:
  print(href.get_attribute('href'))
```

To progress with the project though, maybe the bellow would help:

```
hrefs = article.find_elements_by_xpath('//a')
links = [href.get_attribute("href") for href in hrefs]

for link in link:
  driver.get(link)
  #Add all words in the article to a dictionary with the key being the words and
  #the value being the number of times they occur
```

Comment: This does work indeed. But there are several hrefs included which I don't want to have. The hrefs I want have all a certain class called 'ankeiler__link'. Do you maybe know how I could select only those? Thanks!

Comment: I've written a complete solution as another answer that uses the 'ankeiler__link'.